# What is the standard deviation and mean of the reciprocal of normal distribution in terms of that of the normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

What is the standard deviation and mean of the reciprocal of normal distribution in terms of the standard deviation and mean of the normal distribution?

Comment: Despite the name, the inverse gaussian distribution is not created by taking the reciprocal of a normal distribution. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) page explains this in the introduction: "The name can be misleading: it is an "inverse" only in that, while the Gaussian describes a Brownian motion's level at a fixed time, the inverse Gaussian describes the distribution of the time a Brownian motion with positive drift takes to reach a fixed positive level." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution)

Comment: The reciprocal of a normal distribution does not have a mean value and thus it also does not have a variance. See [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/646428/696482) on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site and this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution).

Comment: Duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70045/mean-and-variance-of-inverse-of-a-normal-rv  (one of many)