# Expectation of the reciprocal of a standard normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

If $\mathbf{X} \sim_{iid} \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$ then we know that the sample mean $\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1/n)$, how would we show that $$\mathbf{E}\left(\frac{1}{\bar{X}}\right) = \infty $$ and more generally for any normal random variable $X$ how would we show $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) = \infty$, I am quite stuck and have tried just using the definition of expectation but my integral has given me no luck so far.

Comment: 1. see the `self-study` [tag wiki info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) $\,$ 2. The premise of the question is false as framed. (If $\mu<0$, it doesn't come out to $\infty$ and if $\mu=0$ it's undefined in the sense that you get the limiting value of the difference of two things that each go to infinity) $\,$ 3. "My integral has given me no luck" is overly vague. What did you try, exactly? Did you consider what a value in the integral-limits of $\infty$ actually  *means* in terms of limits? ($\infty$ *is not a number*) ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: Maybe relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70045/mean-and-variance-of-the-reciprocal-of-a-random-variable

Comment: You don't have to calculate any integrals: you only need to demonstrate that some portion of a relevant integral diverges.

Comment: in what case would this be $\infty$, for what $\mu$?

Comment: The duplicate at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722/ive-heard-that-ratios-or-inverses-of-random-variables-often-are-problematic-in proves the expectation is *undefined* for all $\mu.$  This follows from the simple fact that the value of any Normal density in any finite interval always has a positive lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac12>X>\frac14$, then $2<\frac1X<4$, so in particular $\frac1X>2$.

Similarly

\begin{align}
E\left[\frac1X\right]
&> 2P\left[\frac12>X>\frac14\right]+4P\left[\frac14>X>\frac18\right]+\cdots\\
&>2a(\frac12-\frac14)+4a(\frac14-\frac18)+\cdots\\
&=\frac{a}2 + \frac{a}2 +\cdots
\end{align}
where $a=\min(f(0),f(\frac12))$ and $f$ is the pdf of the given normal distribution.

Since a normal distribution has positive probability everywhere, $a$ is positive. So by adding enough terms to the above expression we can show that $E[1/X]$ is bigger than any specified quantity, i.e. $E[1/X]=\infty$.

Comment: You need to review your first line ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I don’t see an error in the first line

Comment: Seriously, please take another, more careful look at your first line. X cannot be both between 1/4 and a half *and* between 2 and 4 at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b, for helping me see through that fog.

Comment: Note that $1/X$ does not have expectation is very different from $E(1/X) = \infty$. So your conclusion (as well as OP's) is wrong.  To see why, the very fist inequality "$E(1/X) > 2P(...)$" is wrong because $X$ is not a non-negative r.v.!

Comment: +1 for the idea, which is excellent and is easily patched up to address the (valid) objections in the comments.  For instance, invoke definitions in Lebesgue integration to point out that the expectation is undefined when the positive part of a random variable has a divergent integral.  You *cannot* conclude, however, that $E[1/X]$ is itself infinite!